# IS it necessary to register a dll for using it

Tags: c++, dll, dllregistration, borland-c++

Is it necessary to register a dll for using the dll. I heard that 16 bit dll need not be registered then what about 32 bit dll's. I converted a 16bit dll developed in borland c++ 4.52 to 32 bit dll using borland c++ 5.02. My question is whether I need to register it or not?
When i tried to register using the regsvr32, It is giving the error **"the module was loaded but the entry point DllRegistryServer was not found.Make sure it is a valid Dll or OCX and then try again"**.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394388/in-net-is-there-a-need-to-register-the-dll

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need to register DLLs that contain COM classes. These DLLs will contain an exported function called `DllRegisterServer` that will populate the registry will the class-ids of the COM types in the DLL.

For any other type of DLL you don't need to register it.